# Hybrid graphics Intel/Radeon HD 6630M

Tags: graphics, laptop, radeon, gpu, hybrid-graphics

I bought a Dell Vostro 3450 with hybrid GPU and I don't know how to configure properly, I think the fan is running at full speed, also I'm really new in this OS, so I would appreciate all the help you can give me.

Thanks a lot!.

**Hardware**

- 2nd generation Intel®Core™ i5-2450M 2.50GHz
- 6 GB2 Dos canales SDRAM DDR3 a 1333 MHz
- AMD Radeon™ HD 6630M (128-bit) 1GB VRAM

since I'm new, i can't post images :(

Comment: You may struggle a bit if you're graphics are "hybrid", as I suspect they are. Try installing the fglrx driver from "additional drivers" to see if it works. If not, then you might be stuck a bit - maybe try "jupiter" to get your fan noise down.

Answer (score 3):

follow the instructions here:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/ATI

under
**Manually installing Catalyst 12.1**

do everything there step by step until

"sudo amdcccle

To read more about the AMD/ATI Catalyst Control Center click here. Keep in mind that all configuration options for the ATI Catalyst Control Center mentioned there may not be available for your Ubuntu system. "

works with hybrid graphics card (intel / radeon)

you might have to change the filename of the .run file to the filename of the more recent file you downloaded.  (when typing in the terminal, you can use the tab key on your keyboard to autocomplete)

tested in Xubuntu 11.10

Answer (score -1):

Making procedures for the link
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/ATI
the cooler is still in full swing.